# spawn a child process in node.js, data is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here am trying to execute an `exe file`. while executing through command line it is working properly and print the data I want. But using **node.js** 
it print the data as `undefined`. and here is the code am using

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {   
switch (req.url) {    
case '/start':
    console.log("begin...............");        

        req.on("data", function (value) {             
            exec('CALL hello.exe', function(err, data) {                
                 console.log(err)
                console.log(data.toString());                       
           });              
        });
        req.on("end", function () { 
            console.log(data);      // prints undefined 
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log("hello");
            console.log("before--------------");               
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end(data);
        });        
    break;
}
});

server.listen(8080);
console.log("Server running on the port 8080");
```

Comment: Is there anything in `err`?

Comment: no it doent print anything

Comment: i think even it doent prints err the fault is behind exe spawn process is it?is ther any other ways to execute an exe file using node,js

Comment: If the second `console.log()` is undefined, what about the first one?

Comment: both  `console.log(err)
                console.log(data.toString()); `                      
            prints nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this.

I think this will helps you.

```
var http = require('http');
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

switch (req.url) {
  case '/start':
      console.log("begin...............");


        exec('hello.exe', function(err, data) {
          console.log(err);

          console.log(data);
          console.log(data);      // prints undefined 
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
          console.log("hello");
          console.log("before--------------");
          res.writeHead(200);
          res.end(data);
        });

      break;
  }
});

server.listen(8080);
console.log("Server running on the port 8080")
```

Answer (score 2):

Just run the `exec` call like the following.

```
var http = require('http');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

switch (req.url) {
  case '/start':
      console.log("begin...............");


        exec('CALL hello.exe', function(err, data) {
          console.log(err);

          console.log(data);
          console.log(data);      // prints undefined 
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
          console.log("hello");
          console.log("before--------------");
          res.writeHead(200);
          res.end(data);
        });

      break;
  }
});

server.listen(8080);
console.log("Server running on the port 8080");
```

Listening to the `data` event on `req` switches it into a streaming/flowing mode

http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data

Comment: @Sush My bad. I read the code wrong. What is happening is that the request is completing and the `end` event handler is running before the `exec` call finishes. You need to run `exec` in the `req.on('end')` handler.

Comment: so what shoud i write inside  req.on("data", function (value) {});

Comment: so no need to use  req.on("data", function (value) {}); right?

Comment: sorry it doesnt print anything :-(